# How to redirect after successful login in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using building a react app Here I am unable to figure out how to redirect to `/dashboard` after successfull login. Any help would be usefull

In this file i am passing my username and password to my redux action `this.props.login`

> signin.js

```
    handleLoginClick = () => {
        const { inputUserID, inputPassword } = this.state;

        this.login(inputUserID, inputPassword)

      };
    login = (username, password) => {
        this.props.login(username, password);

      };



  render() {
    const {
      showError,
      open,
      inputUserID,
      inputPassword,
      checkRememberID,
      showPhoneNumberDialog,
      showVerifyNumberDialog
    } = this.state;


    return (
      <div className="sign-in-dialog-container">

        <Dialog
          id="dialog-sign-in"
          className="dialog"
          open={open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title"
          style={{

            backgroundColor: '#fff'
          }}
        >
          <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Sign In</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent className="dialog-content">
            <div className="dialog-content-form">
              <div className="form-field">
                <div className="content-label">ID</div>
                <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                  <OutlinedInput
                    fullWidth
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="User Name"
                    value={inputUserID}
                    onChange={this.handleTextChange("inputUserID")}
                    labelWidth={0}
                  />
                </FormControl>
              </div>

              <div className="form-field margin-top-16">
                <div className="content-label">Password</div>
                <FormControl fullWidth variant="outlined">
                  <OutlinedInput
                    fullWidth
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="**********"
                    value={inputPassword}
                    onChange={this.handleTextChange("inputPassword")}
                    labelWidth={0}
                  />
                  {showError ? (
                    <FormHelperText className="password-incorrect-text">
                      Password is incorrect
                    </FormHelperText>
                  ) : null}
                </FormControl>
              </div>

              <div className="form-field">
                <FormControlLabel
                  control={
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={checkRememberID}
                      onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange("checkRememberID")}
                      value="checkRememberID"
                      color="primary"
                    />
                  }
                  label="Remember ID"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="form-field">
                <Button
                  className="next-button custom-button-style"
                  fullWidth
                  onClick={this.handleLoginClick}
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                >
                  Next
                  </Button>
              </div>


            </div>
          </DialogContent>

          <div className="bottom-row">
            <span className="helper-text">
              Don't have an account?
                <span
                onClick={this.handleSignUpClick}
                className="strong cursor-pointer"
              >
                {" "}
                  Sign Up
                </span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.userReducer,
  productPageReducer: state.productPageReducer,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.access_token,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getProductList,
  login,
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SignIn);
```

> authAction.js

```
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
    //User Loading:
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });
    //Make API Call here
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic dG9wc2VsbGVyOnRvcHNlbGxlcg==");

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("username", username);
    formdata.append("password", password);
    formdata.append("grant_type", "password");

    var requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: formdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch("https://api.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com/oauth/token", requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
            res => {
                if (res.access_token && res.refresh_token) {
                    window.localStorage.access_token = res.access_token;
                    window.localStorage.refresh_token = res.refresh_token;
                    dispatch({
                        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                        user: res
                    });
                } else {
                    dispatch({
                        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
                        message: 'Unauthorised User'
                    })
                }

            }
        )
        .catch(error =>
            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_FAIL,
                message: error
            })
        );

}
```

Here i want to figure out how to redirect to `/dashboard` after successfull login.I am also using react-router-dom.

Comment: Can you please share the whole component's code and the `login` function's code from `props`? Thanks!

Comment: @norbitrial wait

Comment: Have you tried this.props.history.push ?

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect , try this  , in header check if logged in , then show the `login page` otherwise `<Redirect>` or simply use ` this.props.history.push()` (as given by the Route as props)

Comment: @shilpa yes i did tryied `this.props.history.push` i am unable to figure out how should i put them here. I need help for this.

Comment: I tried doing something like this `this.login(inputUserID, inputPassword)
      .then(() => this.props.history.push('/dashboard'))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })` but it gives error saying login is not defined

Comment: A no-brainer solution is redirect by `window.location.href = '/dashboard'` in reducer.

Comment: @bravemaster how should i put them inside reducer ?

Comment: `Case LOGIN_SUCCESS: window.location.href='/dashboard'; break;`

Comment: @bravemaster i did put them inside action and this seems to be working.

Comment: put the login above the code @adityakumar

Comment: @bravemaster while putting this in action it resets all my states i guess

Comment: @AnkushVerma I tried putting that about the code

Comment: @AnkushVerma it did not worked

Comment: It was just a hack. Since you're using react-redux, you should include user login state in reducer and combine <Redirect> with it. If you're going to use my hack, there is a tip for you. You did something wrong with window.localStroage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like after successful sign-in attempt, { user } state at your redux store change.

therefore you might consider add this at signin.js

---

```
          import {Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';  

          class SignIn extends Component { 
          ...rest class..
          render ()
          const { user } = this.props;
          return( 
          <>
           { if (user)<Redirect to="/dashboard" />;} // in case { user } is null at initial state, otherewise change the checker... 
          ...rest code...
          </>
          )
}
```

---

working example - https://github.com/zero-to-mastery/visual-music/blob/development/src/pages/Login/Login.js

Comment: Is there any other way i am using class component here. And I won't be able to use hooks here i guess.

Comment: yes, https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

and will edit my answer

Comment: sorry friend, just now looked upon all of your uploaded code and not just actions..

seems like { Redirect } is really all you need, and in case that you created { Router } at former component

Answer (score 2):

You can do this but DO NOT:

```
CASE LOGIN_SUCCESS:
   window.location.href = '/dashboard';
   break;
```

This is just a hack. Redirecting with window.location.href makes your app lose SPA advantages.

Since you're using React-redux, you must hold user login state in reducer. And let `App.jsx` subscribe login state and if it's false render a `Redirect` component.

**Why your app forgets login state after redirect:**

Because you're doing something wrong with `window.localStorage`:

```
window.localStorage.whatever_token = 'foobarbaz';
```

This won't work. `localStorage` was not meant to be used like this.

Instead, you should:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('my_token', 'awesome_jwt_token');
```

Later:

```
const isLoggedIn = () = > {
  const token =  window.localStorage.getItem('my_token');
  if (token) {
    //    can ommit this flow
    //    const isLoggedIn = askServerIfThisTokenIsValid(token);
    //    if (isLoggedIn) {
    //        return true;
    //    } else {
    //        window.localStorage.removeItem('my_token');
    //    }
    return true; // but not safe - handle 403 error in all api calls
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the redux state change to decide which component to render. For instance, you can have a property like 'IsLoggedIn' in the redux state and when its 'true' render the '/dashboard' component. something like:

```
if(IsLoggedIn) return (<Dashboard />)
else return (<Login />)
```

Comment: Is this the right way to do this ? I mean I have token in my localstorage as well now i am confused should i choose access token or should i define a state and then deal with it  ?

Comment: Since you have a token when the login is successful, use that field to check which component is being rendered. For example if(token) is empty return nothing or else return the dashboard page.